# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect java nio

Tags: java, nio

```
**java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
```

I have this exception when i use socketchannel between two pcs on the same local network strong text .. but when i use on the same PC is connects and send bytes without any exception..any help?

```
the error happens when calling connect(socketAddress);

    **socketChannel.connect(socketAddress);****
```

Answer (score 0):

First check the connectivity between the two PCs by using `ping` from one machine using the IP

```
ping 192.168.x.x
```

If the ping works, double check the firewall settings of both the PCs